# fread with gunzip: What's the more memory efficient way?

Tags: r, memory, data.table, gzip, fread

If I have a large data file which is zipped with gzip, say `dat.gz`, what is more **memory** efficient?

```
mydat <- fread("gunzip -c dat.gz")
```

or, first unzip/uncompress the file to say, `dat`, and then do

```
mydat <- fread("dat")
```

I'm concerned with memory rather than speed, to prevent R from crashing.

Comment: For memory issues, it might be worthwhile to load the file in several steps using the `skip=` and `nrows=` options of `fread` (not sure if this changes anything though)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a 5000x5000 matrix to temp.csv and profiled the memory usage of the two approaches using profvis:

```
profvis({system("gunzip -c temp.csv.gz > temp.csv"); mat <- fread("temp.csv")})
```

Memory usage: 190.9 MB

```
profvis({fread("gunzip -c temp.csv.gz")})
```

Memory usage: 190.8 MB

I ran it several times, and the memory usage fluctuated between 190-191 for both commands.  So I conclude that the memory usage is the same.